# (Rails) Nokogiri returns nil from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

```
def noko_scrape
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  url = "http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/ta?s=ANZ.AX&t=2y"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  puts "Retrieved doc =" + doc[1..20]
  ...
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError in StocksController#noko_scrape can't convert nil into String
```

(referring to the last line).

It appears Nokogiri is finding errors in the HTML and failing accordingly.

Any suggestions on how to get round this?

Comment: What do you expect to get in the output?

Comment: The problem is in the '&' that has the url. I've tried changing the '&' to ';' there is no error anymore, but the url is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed errors in the HTML, as you can see if you try `doc.errors`:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/ta?s=ANZ.AX&t=2y"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.errors
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag nobr invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag nobr invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag nobr invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>]
```

However, this has nothing to do with the error you're getting. You are trying to convert `doc[1..20]` to a string, but calling elements of a Nokogiri document has no meaning because the document is not an array. Hence, they are all `nil`:

```
doc[1]
#=> nil
doc[2]
#=> nil
```

(Do the same for any other URL and you'll get the exact same result.)

If, what you want is the HTML for the doc, you can get that with the `to_html` method:

```
doc.to_html
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>...
```